# http redirect to https

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

I have a site (http://intranet/) that has an alternative access mapping configured with an external url (https://intranet.company.com/). Users going to http://intranet.company.com instead of https://intranet.company.com/) get the IIS7 default Welcome logo.

I'd like to redirect any users going to http to the https site if possible. Not sure the best direction to take: whether I should do this is SharePoint, IIS, or on the firewall somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to use the redirect module in IIS to redirect http:// to https://.  Of course, in addition to having the AAM set, you must also configure IIS for that site to allow 443 access, and install an SSL certificate.

The reason folks accessing your site via http:// get the default IIS 7 logo is because you don't have an AAM mapped to http://intranet.company.com, so they are getting the default website configured in IIS and bound to port 80.  Binding your sharepoint site in IIS to http://intranet.company.com AND using the redirect on that site to redirect to https:// will fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running redirects in SharePoint you can either use a reverse proxy (such as ForeFront TMG or ISA 2006) to do it for you, or simply use the "Extend web application" to effectively create a new IIS publishing the same content.

This will give multiple benefits among which - different URL, authentication provider, different App Pool (if you choose to )  - and create for your automatic the entry in the AAM (Alternate Access Mappings)  - all these while having users automatically targeting the same content database.

There are of course solutions, e.g. IIS modules but there are workarounds, not actual solutions!

Let me know if you need more details,
C:\Marius

Comment: Why is using IIS redirect a workaround?

Comment: Because SharePoint doesn't "know" about this, which also means that every request will be automatically sent out in your email notifications, alerts and workflows with an Internal URL - try sharing document links with your users via email (as one example). Then from this other consequences - mostly bad occur from the same thing  -e.g  HTTP headers are wrongfully sent.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the redirect through IIS. (Redirection is straightforward in IIS7.) You'll have to set up the SSL cert and managed path in SharePoint CA before you configure the redirection in IIS7. Once you confirm you can hit your site with http and https, configure the redirect.

(regarding the firewall. I was once told by an network engineer that an http(80) to https(443) simple redirect may not work on a firewall. Essentially, this is the firewall forwards the http request to the 443 port, but does not actually change the protocol to https. I could be wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a httpmodule or code behind in master page to redirect